# How to convert a string so as to prevent Embedded nul in string error

Tags: r

I am getting a fairly common Embedded nul in string error when converting a long string with `rawToChar()`

#### Minimal example

This works as expected

```
c(65:68) %>% as.raw %>% rawToChar 
# [1] "ABCD"
```

But this errors

```
c(65:68, 0, 70) %>% as.raw %>% rawToChar 
# Error in rawToChar(.) : embedded nul in string: 'ABCD\0F'
```

So it appears the `0` in `c(0, 70)` is problematic

```
c(0, 70) %>% as.raw %>% rawToChar
```

But only under certain circumstances, as this does not error (it returns an empty string)

```
c(0) %>% as.raw %>% rawToChar
# ""
```

#### Notes

- It appears [this is a known bug in R emanating from c](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Embedded-nuls-in-strings-td916868.html).

#### Question

How can we convert a string, or the string `as.raw()`, so as to reliably avoid this error when converting using `rawToChar()`?

Comment: Try `c(65:68, 0, 70) %>% as.raw %>% setdiff('00') %>% rawToChar# "ABCDF"`

Comment: @akrun this works on the MRE. I will try on my real world example and report back shortly

Comment: Use `c(65:68, numeric(0), 70) %>% as.raw %>% rawToChar` isntead of `0`.

Comment: `c(65:68, 0, 70) %>% as.raw %>% rawToChar(multiple = TRUE) %>% paste(collapse = "") `

Comment: or `c(65:68, 0, 70) %>% as.raw %>% {.[. != 0]} %>% rawToChar()`

Comment: If you are getting this string from a file you can use `readLines(..., skipNul = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
c(65:68, 0, 70) %>%
    as.raw %>% 
    setdiff('00') %>%
   rawToChar
```